# CasperJS remote debugging option

Tags: remote-debugging, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to use remote debugging option for **casperJS**.

I am running this on port `6666`.

```
$casperjs --remote-debugger-port=6666 myscript.js
```

The debugger starts and I am able to access WebKit inspector on url

```
http://localhost:6666/
```

I am seeing first URL as `about:blank`.

When I click on it, Web Page inspector loads.

When I type `_run()` in console, I am getting

**Reference Error, _run is not defined error.**

I am not able to go ahead further. Please let me know if I need to do corrections somewhere.

Also, do I have to set explicit breakpoints in CasperJS script. If I have to, then how ?

**UPDATE 1**

Tried  --remote-debugger-autorun=yes

```
$casperjs --remote-debugger-port=6666 --remote-debugger-autorun=yes myscript.js
```

This runs the script immediately as stated in help. However, the debugger still runs and process does not exit.

**OUTPUT**

Now I can see requested URL below about:blank.

When I click on about:blank or requested url, WebKit inspector opens.

But I am stuck again.

**UPDATE 2**

Also tried to execute examples ported with phantomJS.

Result is same. I am stuck on a blank WebKit Inspector window.

Answer (score 6):

Try `__run()` instead of `_run()`.

You can also place breakpoints at design time when you write "debugger;" in your script. The debugger will break at those lines.

I have another problem I am researching now - the casper.exit() function doesn't terminate the phantom process. It displays the following line:

```
Phantom::exit() called but not quitting in debug mode.
```

One needs to kill the process manually...

Comment: This. The second underscore has been the bane of my frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the ticket ATM, but I don't think you can start casperJS in the debugger mode.  However, you can CasperJS as a library to a PhantomJS script:

phantom.casperPath = '/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.0.1/libexec/';
phantom.injectJs('/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.0.1/libexec/bin/bootstrap.js');